# Why would you instantiate a Date with -1 as the argument?

Tags: java, datetime

I know this may be an obvious question, but I  am looking at this code:

```
private Date lastActivity = new Date(-1);
```

And am curious what this does - the [Date class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) has six different constructors, and only one can take a single argument of `long`, like so:

```
public Date(long date)
```

which:

> Allocates a Date object and initializes it to represent the specified
>   number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the
>   epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

So is -1 just a placeholder? I appreciate any tips or advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So is -1 just a placeholder? I appreciate any tips or advice.

Probably not in the sense that the term placeholder is normally used.  (That is something that stands for ... or holds a place for ... something else.)

It is more likely to be a value that represents a boundary condition for the purposes of the computation.  In this particular case, the variable name `lastActivity` seems to imply this.  I would imagine that this is part of some algorithm to determine the latest time of "an activity" ... and that the `Date(-1)` object will be taken as meaning "the activity never occurred".  They could also have used `null` or a flag to represent this ... but using a "funky" Date object probably simplifies the logic of the algorithm a bit.

A "sentinel value" is a good term for this ... but "marker value" not so good, because it is not actually marking anything.

(In a sense, the choice of `-1` is arbitrary.  It could be any value ... provided that it didn't correspond to a time point that might be encountered by the algorithm.  Using `-1` is ideal if the time points are always going to be after the UNIX epoch ... January 1, 1970.  But if it potentially has to deal with historical dates, then maybe `Long.MIN_VALUE` would be better.  Either way ... this is all likely to be moot in the context of your homework.)

Answer (score 19):

it is `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT` ***minus one millisecond*** (negative numbers are dates in back of the beginning of the epoch)

Comment: Yes, but do you think it at all likely that lastActivity actually happened then?  No, this is almost certainly a marker object.

Answer (score 17):

One would typically do this to get a "well known" Date, perhaps for validation or comparisons (all "real Dates" are greater than this one), as a "marker object" to indicate that the Date is really unknown/illegal/pending but you don't want to use null for some reason, or perhaps for a Unit Test.

O.K., looking up the more proper terms for what I called a "marker value", I get sentinel value, flag value, trip value, rogue value, signal value, or dummy data.   see [wikipedia article here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value)

Comment: Can you even do that?  I figured the `Date` object would throw an exception if you tried to set it to an invalid value. [by-design], I guess.

Comment: I've never tried with -1 but have often used new Date(0) for this purpose

Comment: @Adel  yes, it's a bogus date, but a "well known" bogus date.  :-)  In many examples you use -1 for a count or index to indicate "not found".  (e.g. String.indexOf()).  In that example, -1 is a well known bogus position.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's not an invalid value. It's December 31, 1969 23:59:59:9999 GMT

Comment: @user949300 and @Adel There is nothing illegal with `new Date(-1)`. See my answer

Comment: The `Date(long)` constructor doesn't reject any values. And why would `new Date(-1)` be a "bogus" date? Depending on how it's implemented, this could just as well mean 1 millisecond _before_ 1970-01-01 00:00:00.

Comment: @Wormbo  o.k., technically, "bogus" may be too strong a term.  But since the code was hardcoded at -1, unless there is an explicit comment that this means that specific date I would assume that it is a marker / "bogus" date.  It is unlikely that lastActivity actually occurred in 1969 unless it was something about kissing your high-school sweetheart at New Year's.  (and in London!)

Comment: Well yeah, it's probably a marker date, a "non-null `null` value", if you will. But unlike the -1 return from failed search operations it's still a valid value. Just a bit unusual. :-)

Comment: @Wormbo agreed.  Frankly, I always thought -1 was an illegal argument, so I learned something here.

Answer (score 4):

This is called a [sentinel value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value). The point of it is usually to indicate that data is not available, that a series of data has come to an end, etc. By using a specific, obviously invalid value, you save the effort of maintaining a separate `isValid` or `isFinished` field.

Opinions differ on whether or not this is good practice. When the convention is very well-known, as in the ASCII `\0` that terminates a C string, it is generally accepted. In other circumstances there is often the possibility that you might expand the range of what is considered 'valid' in the future, and then you'll be in a bind when dealing with legacy data. It also violates the single responsibility principle: that piece of data can represent two rather different pieces of information, which hurts maintainability because the code reader may not be aware of the hidden potential special meaning, and the type system doesn't help you discover it.